# FLV Cue point on video Import

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm having trouble with a simple AS3 (CS5.5) project I have imported a video encoded through Adobe media encoder as a FLV file and have added a Navigation Cue Point at the end of the video as I would like the video to simply go to a frame number when the video has ended so it doesn't stop on that video.

I have used a code I have used on many occasions in AS2 which I put on a keyframe at the top where the video runs under and give the video an instance name of vid:

```
stop();
var listenerObject:Object = new Object();
listenerObject.cuePoint = function(eventObject:Object):Void {
    // Put any code you like here<br>
    trace("Cue point name: " + eventObject.info.name);
    trace("Cue point type: " + eventObject.info.type);

    if(eventObject.info.name=="movieend")
    {
        gotoAndPlay(135);
    }
}
vid.addEventListener("cuePoint", listenerObject);
```

For some reason this is coming up with an error in AS3.

Ideally I just want the code go to a frame number when the video finishes instead of staying on the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be a little out of whack. Try this.

```
stop();

vid.addEventListener(MetadataEvent.CUE_POINT, cp_listener);

function cp_listener(eventObject:MetadataEvent):void {

trace("Cue point name: " + eventObject.info.name);
trace("Cue point type: " + eventObject.info.type);

       if (eventObject.info.name == "movieend") {
         //flvPlaybak.seek(0);
         //flvPlaybak.play();

             gotoAndPlay(135);
       }

}
```

Comment: No this didn't work sorry. Am getting an error message saying "Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MetadataEvent." Yeah the code is a little bit all over the place as copied it from a site ages ago but it seemed to work. I just want the video to go to a frame when the video hits the cue point.

Comment: You need to import the class:  import fl.video.MetadataEvent;